# Why was anti-semitism such a central issue in German politics?

Tags: germany, jews, antisemitism

Provided that the Jewish population was not more than 0,76% why the presence of Jews was considered such an important problem in German politics and culture from the middle of the 19th century till the second world war?

There are lots of detailed descriptions of antisemitism during the second half of 19th and till the destruction of German Jewry. I don't know any writer explaining the reasons behind the emergence of anti-semitism on historical terms though there are some psychological explanations (Arrendt,Frankfurt school)

Comment: Can you add a timeframe?

Comment: @nvoigt from the middle of the 19th century till the second world war

Comment: I think this is too broad if it covers such a longer period. Plus, after WWI the answer is *very* simple: 'the betrayal theory' where they subverted German efforts in the war, causing the defeat. This also has a specific name but I can't remember it at the moment and quick searches didn't bring it up either so *perhaps it is not that simple* :P

Comment: @gktscrk I think you mean Dolchstoßlegende? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stab-in-the-back_myth

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I have found nothing so far dealing with the fact why anti-semitism shaped the german society. If you could suggest me any source I would either delete the question or provide an answer myself, for the benefit of the other users

Comment: I'm not sure what would be a good starting point for research (a wikipedia page "Antisemitism in Germany" does not exist), so I'm not sure what kind of prior researchone should expect.

Comment: I did a quick google search and found several references. [Stab in the back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stab-in-the-back_myth), [adl](https://www.adl.org/sites/default/files/documents/assets/pdf/education-outreach/Brief-History-on-Anti-Semitism-A.pdf), [UCLA](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~webfac/eichengreen/Voth.pdf), [CDEC](http://www.quest-cdecjournal.it/index.php?issue=3), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisemitism_in_Europe#19th_and_early_20th_century), etc.

Comment: TBH before WW1 anti-semitism seems to have been much less a problem in Germany than France, Russia and even Autria-Hungary. 0.76% would be nationwide, but in certain jobs and places such as banks they would be much more represented, which is what fueled many consipration theorists and antisemitism in the 1st place.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Admittedly, Google results may vary by location. I had difficulty locating the stab-in-the-back theory even though I approximately knew what it was named.

Comment: I do not think that this is too broad. Sure antisemitism in Germany changed over the years, but understanding the later period is difficult without taking a look at the earlier period around the unification in 1871. Sadly, this is what some people do when they try to find the roots of German antisemitism and even the causes of the Nazi dictatorship in WW1 and the Dolchstoßlegende. For the earlier period, I would recommend looking at the history of the [Berlin movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_movement).

Comment: @0range: You make a good point. German (Imperial) cities had had Jewish quarters and segregation for a long time as well, so perhaps restricting this in that way is unhelpful. In which case, we should determine whether early modern antisemitism had the same reasons as later antisemitism in nation states (I'm not sure of the answer here).

Comment: Among other reasons: Napoleon liberated the Jews in Germany and nascent German nationalism was powerfully resentful of Napoleon.

Comment: @antlersoft the only useful comment thanks